# Unexpected error due to lower and upper limits when using fminbnd function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, limit, runtime-error

I am using lower limit and upper limit in the `fminbnd` function according to the legit domain values of my coefficients as following:

```
[x,fval,exitflag] = fminbnd(@(x) minimize_me(sill, x(1), x(2), x(3), cov), [x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u], opts);
```

Where the `[x1l x2l x3l]` and `[x1u x2u x3u]` are the vectors representing the lower limit and upper limit for the optimized coefficients. The domain of my problem is given as following:

```
0<=x1l<=5
0<=x1u<=5

0<=x2l<=5
0<=x2u<=5

0<=x3l<=180
0<=x3u<=180
```

The strange problem is that I get an error shown below even for choosing some values within my domain:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in ==> fminbnd at 271
    x = xf + si * max( abs(d), tol1 );
```

For example I get an error if I choose:

`[x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u] = [0 0 0], [5 5 180]` or `[x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u] = [1 1 0], [5 5 180]` or `[x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u] = [1 2 0], [5 5 180]` etc.

However, I don't get an error if I choose `[x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u] = [5 5 0], [5 5 180]` or `[x1l x2l x3l], [x1u x2u x3u] = [3 0 0], [3 5 180]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html), `fminbnd` only works with functions that take a single scalar as an argument.

Take a look at `fminsearchbnd` on the file exchange:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd.

Comment: I have scalar as an argument. As I said, it works with some limits and it doesn't work with some other limits even within the limit domain.

Comment: The anonymous function that you are passing into `fminbnd` takes a single argument, but it is a 3-element vector, not a scalar. Or am I quite confused? No idea why it would "work" with some limits and not others, but if my understanding is correct, it's not actually giving you the right answer ... it's just not giving an error.

Comment: @DanBecker: You are right :-). The reason I was passing multiple arguments was because I had first looked at `fminsearchbnd` function (a user shared Matlab function) which allows passing multiple coefficients for optimization. I thought there doesn't seems any difference b/w `fminbnd` and `fminsearchbnd` after which when I used the former function I was getting the result. However, as you said the results were not correct and my using multiple coefficients with `fminbnd` was also not correct. Thanks!